# How can I add PHP support to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, ide

I don't like splitting up my development environments, but I build projects for clients who use both .NET systems and Apache-based systems.  This means I am forced to split my time between Visual Studio for the .NET and Dreamweaver or another IDE for the PHP-based work.  I don't want to use two IDEs - I'd much rather build everything in one.

I prefer VS for its intellisense support.  It's also easier to track down bugs in JavaScript used between two different projects when the syntax coloring is consistent - every IDE colors text slightly differently, making the same file look different in each environment.

Aside from [VS.Php](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php), what solutions exist for adding PHP support to the Visual Studio IDE?  VS.Php looks promising, but I don't want to shell out any cash for something that may or may not satisfy my need.  Since PHP itself is free, I'm wondering if anyone's bothered to build a free extension that offers the same support.  Is this possible?  Or should I just bite the bullet and go with VS.Php?

Comment: Arguably belongs on Stack Overflow.  It's a corner case, but developers are more likely to know the answer.

Comment: VS.Php actually comes with a 30 days trial period. You can try it before you buy.

Comment: "If you have a question about ... computer software."  The last time I asked a question like this on SO I was told to ask it here instead ...

Comment: **Since this didn't get much response on SU, and since it meets the criteria for SO, it was decided to migrate it here**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VS.PHP is what I use](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/download.php)

Comes with a free trial and adds support to VS.

Comment: Though I explicitly asked suggestions *other* than VS.Php, this is the best solution - and answer - available.

Comment: Ya, I really did look for other solutions when I was vetting this. I didn't find any others.

Answer (score 1):

[WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) is a free Microsoft product.

Though it does not offer a "plug-in" mechanism for Visual Studio, it should give you a lot of what you and others are looking for.

[image: screenshot]